# Android Tab Host Fragment + AsyncTask on Scroll error

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I currently have a three  fragments + tab host and working its nice. In Fragment 1, I used `AsyncTask` to show the data and used  `setOnScrollListener` to load more items in the `ListView` and all works good.

But the problem is when I selected (Fragment 3, last) Tab 3 and go back to tab 1 (Fragment 1, the first), it only shows the last data where it looks like I scrolled down.

On simpler note: When I selected the last fragment (tab 3) and back, I have the same effect when I scroll down (`setOnScrollListener`). To understand the situation more, please look at the image below.

[image]

```
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

    ListView listView;
    ContactPost_Adapter contactPost_adapter;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    public boolean flag_loading = false;
    private int requestCount = 1;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        final View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout1,container,false);onStart();

        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.laner_txt);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_post);

        new BackgroundSug(getActivity()).execute("1");


        contactPost_adapter = new ContactPost_Adapter(getActivity(),R.layout.post_row);


        listView.setAdapter(contactPost_adapter);
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }
            private void getData() {

                new BackgroundSug(getActivity()).execute("1");
                requestCount++;



            }
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
                {


                if(flag_loading == false)
                    {


                     flag_loading = true;
                        getData();
                    }
                }
            }
        });




        return v;

    }


    public void bindGridview()
    {
        String  langm = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().toLowerCase();

        new BackgroundSug(getActivity()).execute("1",langm);

    }
    private class BackgroundSug extends AsyncTask<String ,String ,String> {
        Context ctx;

        BackgroundSug(Context ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String login_url = "http://10.13.528.88/sh_post.php?oq="+ String.valueOf(requestCount);
            String reg_account = params[0];
            String lang_val = params[1];


            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

/*****
```